# navigate buttons using arrows in html

Tags: html

When I hold ctrl + shift and then press arrows, I want to navigate between buttons.

I'm using electron if it helps

```html
<div class="items1" style="border-radius: 12px; border: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid;">
  <p class="txt">Insert Essentials</p>
  <div>
    <button class="button" id="insertf" onclick="template()">Template</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button" id="insertf" onclick="field()">Command</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button" id="insertf" onclick="neededfield()">Message Event</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button" id="insertf" onclick="dropdown()">Ready Event</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button" id="insertf" onclick="breaks()">Bot Login</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button" id="insertf" onclick="message()">Send Message</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button" id="insertf" onclick="bottoken()">Token</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button" id="insertf" onclick="botprefix()">Prefix</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button" id="insertf" onclick="save()">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok thanks im kinda new to this

Comment: [Please search your title first](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+navigate+ctrl+shift+arrow+site:stackoverflow.com)